# Length of tab character

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to type a specific width of tab using `\t`, or is it a system defined length?

Example code:

```
print 'test\ttest 2'
```

Comment: Sorry. I meant the width of a tab. For example, on my Macbook, a tab is 4 spaces wide. On my Raspberry Pi, it's 8 spaces wide.

Comment: Many editors can be configured to change how many spaces they show for tabs. A tab is a control character, it doesn't havete a specific width. It's up to whatever program reads it to decide whether to display it as a number of spaces, or a line or something else - so it's not a property of your Macbook or your Raspberry Pi, it's a property of the particular text editors and terminal settings you are using on them

Comment: I know this is old, but, though it is not possible to define the tab size, what you can do is put the values into a formatted string, like: print("{:<10}: {}".format("test", "test 2"))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not possible. But, you can replace every tab with custom amounts of spaces using [`str.expandtabs`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.expandtabs):

```
print repr('test\ttest 2'.expandtabs())
# output: 'test    test 2'

print repr('test\ttest 2'.expandtabs(2))
# output: 'test  test
```

**Edit**: note that when using `str.expandtabs`, the width of tab will depend on where in string the tab is:

```
print repr('test\ttest 2'.expandtabs(8))
print repr('tessst\ttest 2'.expandtabs(8))
# output: 'test    test 2'
#         'tessst  test 2'
```

If you want each tab to be replaced by specifyed number of spaces, you can use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
print repr('test\ttest 2'.replace('\t', ' ' * 8))
print repr('tessst\ttest 2'.replace('\t', ' ' * 8))
# output: 'test        test 2' 
#         'tessst        test 2'
```

Comment: Agreed. As you can tell comparing your Macbook and Raspberry Pi, the width of a tab is determined by the program displaying it. So the answer changes with every program. The above solution may give more predictable results, but frankly the width a space is also not inherently fixed. If a program shows it in courier font, it might be, but what it if it shows it in 'Arial'? Or what if (like a webbrowser) it treats multiple white space characters as a single space.

Comment: @RobertB: Generally, when you have any data, you can't control how it will be processed... and you don't need to. It's not your problem when your correct output is incorrectly processed. (I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, please ask me further if I didn't).

Comment: You are asking if you can control how data is displayed. The answer is 'No, it is controlled by whatever is displaying it'.

Comment: @RobertB The reason the spaces may not seem the same size is because some fonts are monospaced where all characters take up the same width and others take up as much space as is required by the drawing of the character and nothing much more except minor padding... For any type of coding and for debugging output, I recommend using a monospaced font to ensure everything lines up, especially if you're like me and have written specific functions to handle output of data such as string.FormatColumn( width, text, ... ) which lets you specify width of column, truncating extra, and repeat both...