# How are spaces between variables calculated in python's command environment?

Tags: python-3.x

For examlpe:

```
name = input('please enter your first name:\t')

last_name = input('please enter your last name:\t')

print('first name = ',name)

print('last name = ', last_name)
```

The out put is:

```
please enter your first name: meisam

please enter your last name:       ilka
```

why is there so much space between ":" and ilka???

Comment: I can't reproduce your code behavior but I believe that problem is your `\t` in your code. Different settings for tabulation can lead to different results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of tab character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421405/length-of-tab-character)

Answer (score 0):

> why is there so much space between ":" and ilka???

Because that is the tab width that you have configured in your terminal.