# \t didn't appear in the for loop

Tags: python

I'm practicing format fuction and when I use this code with \t in it, the first 9 output did not have any big space
`

```
import random
lst = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(51)]
for index, val in enumerate(lst):
    print(f'{index=}\t{val=}')
```

`

It works with \n but not \t, I don't know why. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: I ran your code and it worked, are you sure?

Comment: The first 9 outputs are 7 characters then tab (pads to eight) and then continues. However, when index is 10 you have 'index=10' which is exactly 8 characters so you then get a full tab after that. It's doing what you told it to do

Comment: Thanks Cobra, I understand what you said, but what do you mean by 'pads to eight'?

Comment: @Caphefacansa It depends on how your terminal interprets a tab character. For example, on macOS the Terminal application will use a tab width of 8 by default. So if you print 'abc\tz' the actual output width will be 9 because 5 [visualised] spaces will be added after the first 3 significant characters (8-3). It's all about visualisation. If you write 'abc\tz' to a file it will only occupy 5 characters - not 9

Answer (score 0):

It's just the terminal following tab(4 spaces in your case) convention. So add spaces before and after `\t`.

Comment: 4 spaces? Are you sure?

Comment: @Cobra, as tab is configured to 4 spaces and his output is of length 7, he couldn't visualise the space in output terminal. So I recommended him to add spaces before and after \t and it would solve the visualising issue.

Comment: @Immaturetrader What makes you think that tab is equivalent to 4 spaces? Could be anything. Sure, 4 is common but it could be anything. 8 is very common too

Comment: @Cobra, you can set tab to any count you like. In general if you download VScode and check settings, you will find 4 spaces for tab, users change them later. As the question is asked by a new contributor I answered viewing his default settings. you can check any editor, by default tab is 4.

Comment: @Immaturetrader Thank you for your guidance. I checked my editor (vi) and it's definitely 8. Take care when offering "advice" to people with far more experience than yourself

Comment: @Cobra, You are comparing vim to other editors. Please read this : [Default tab size](https://superuser.com/questions/355863/why-is-the-default-tab-size-8-spaces-where-does-this-come-from-and-why-is-it-th). I don't understand why you are taking it personal, I didn't advice you in any of the comments, those innuendos are uncalled for. In general most starters use vscode so I have referred it. Anyways sorry if I have hit your nerve in any way, I really didn't mean it.

Answer (score 0):

All results has `\t`

Run your code with `python yourcode.py | cat -T`

This is the results. `^I` is the tab.

```
$ python yourcode.py | cat -T
index=0^Ival=14
index=1^Ival=46
index=2^Ival=87
index=3^Ival=83
index=4^Ival=28
index=5^Ival=77
index=6^Ival=34
index=7^Ival=66
index=8^Ival=64
index=9^Ival=80
index=10^Ival=28
index=11^Ival=21
index=12^Ival=64
index=13^Ival=79
index=14^Ival=92
index=15^Ival=67
index=16^Ival=69
index=17^Ival=50
```

Man page of `cat` says

> ```
>   -T, --show-tabs
>          display TAB characters as ^I
> ```

You may change the length of TAB. Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421405/length-of-tab-character)